# to remove casing from sausages or not?

Tags: sausages

Is it best to remove sausage casing before cooking sausages or not?
I don't see it mentioned in recipes, but have seen it done by people when cooking. Is this a matter of preference or is there any improvement to quality of flavor when casings are removed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a personal preference.

Personally, I'd never dream of doing it, unless it was for a dish that specifically called for it, or one that requires 'chunks'*. Part of the job of the casing is to keep the sausages moist. You shouldn't even prick them with a fork whilst frying [yet some people do].

For chunks, there's a distinct difference between frying them whole & cutting up than cutting then frying. The first retains the shape, the second tends to squeeze out of the ends as the casing shrinks.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply about the final preparation.  Casings are neutral when it comes to flavor.  If you prefer to serve your sausages whole, in the casing, they might add to the "snap", or mouth feel when you bite into it.  Otherwise, it is dependent on the recipe.